# Notepad++ Alternative string in Perl Regex

Tags: perl

I am trying to implement some of my old notepad++ regex search in perl.

I using following command.

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/\\cellx10464\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\sl320\\plain\\f4\\fs20\\b\\cf0 Patent Information\\b0(?:.*[\r\n]+){88}\\cellx10464\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\sl320\\plain\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 \\f1\\fs20\\cf0 US \d{11}(?:.*[\r\n]+){52}\\cellx10464\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\sl320\\plain\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 \\f1\\fs20\\cf0 (US [0-9]{5,7})[\r\n]+\\cell\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\sl320\\plain\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 \\f1\\fs20\\cf0 (\w\d)[\r\n]+\\cell\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\sl320\\plain\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9,]{3} [0-9]{4}[\r\n]+\\cell\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\sl320\\plain\\f1\\fs20\\cf0 \\f1\\fs20\\cf0  [\r\n]+\\cell\\pard\\plain\\intbl\\s0\\ql\\fi0\\li0\\ri0\\plain/tttttt$1 $2/smg' 1.rtf
```

**Edit**
but it is giving error.(after changing from suggestions)

> Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

This is my first encounter with perl. What am I missing (or adding)?

**Using strawberry perl for windows.**

Comment: I think problem is with (?:.*[\r\n]+){88}

Comment: `\1` and `\2` are called `$1` and `$2` in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apology for the trouble. This already has answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712181/strawberry-perl-regex-windows-7

use of " instead of ' in windows.